# How to solve a React module's warnings

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone solve these warnings?

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'cdbreact'. 'e:/muiandreactjs/muiandreact/node_modules/cdbreact/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cdbreact` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cdbreact';
```

I have installed the cdbreact tools but the problem is showing just like above when I mouse over "cdbreact" declarations.

I try using the alert properties from [here](https://github.com/Mystereyn/cdbreact-tools-for-learning), it's a success.

Comment: it also mentioned solution did you tried that
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cdbreact` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cdbreact';

Comment: Yes, i was tried using npm i --save-dev @types/cdbreact before... should i adding a new declarations file .d.ts?

Comment: go ahead try may be some kind of package error